# How to execute PHP query at a set time everyday + advice on approach

Tags: php, mysql

I am seeking some advice about a feature I am considering to implement.

I have a variable `$row['summa'];` which obtains the total number of rows in two tables. It basically is a count for all the flagged posts, and flagged comments in total. So, I have a echo `$row['summa'];` of `10` meaning in both `flagged_comments` and `flagged_posts` I have `10` rows, which is correct.

Now using this, I want to create a new table in my database with the following fields:

```
id
date
total_flagged
```

I need it so that every day, (preferably at midnight each day) a PHP query is executed which gets the date (I would prefer day, ie. Monday, Tuesday etc) and get the total amount of flagged incidents for that day.

Example:

Today is Sunday. Sunday had, in total, 10 flagged incidents. Therefore, at midnight, a query will be executed to INSERT:

```
id: 1
date: sunday
total_flagged: 10
```

And then, once executed, the total flagged will reset, so that I can determine total flagged incidents for Monday.

The reason I need all the above is that for my admin side, I am trying to implement a graph, which will dynamically update based on PHP data from the database. The graph will show the days on the x-axis and number of flagged incidents on the y-axis.

But, because of this date/day attached to the graph and database, I will probably have to add a new column called `date_flagged` to both `flagged_posts` and `flagged_comments` table.

I just don't believe my approach to what I am trying to achieve is the most sustainable. Just seeking advice on how to approach this issue and how I can execute a PHP query everyday at a set time.

Comment: short answer: **cron**

Comment: slightly longer answer: cron triggering EITHER a lynx launched web accessible script that does that, OR, cron triggering a straight PHP script, which means you can't count on any of the apache _SERVER data or include paths etc being there, but if you set all that manually that's not an issue.

Comment: browser arg? just use cli php

Answer (score 1):

The `cron`approach has already been mentioned. However, the validity of the data generated this way depends on a reliable execution of cron. To make this approach robust against possible error conditions (e.g. server down at midnight, unexpected changes of crontab by other administrators etc.), you will have to build in some checks and safeguards. Also, if you are hosting your system with a provider and need to migrate at some later time, the new provider might not offer `cron` functionality. Just saying – there are dependencies to think of when mixing `cron`with web and database services.

I would prefer a solution which does not depend on `cron` and possible race conditions. This solution would involve extending your database with a journal of the date/time a comment or post has been flagged. This would allow you to calculate the statistics for a particular day at any later time, instead of having to depend on timely consolidation at midnight. This would already avoid some of the problems if `cron` happened to fail for some reason.

To avoid having to use `cron` altogether, I'd set up the admin side such that the PHP script which generates the graph checks first if the graph data for the requested day(s) already has been calculated. If not, it calculates the statistics and stores them in the database. Subsequent calls to the script would fetch the calculated data from the database directly. This would imply a longer script execution and response time for the first caller of the day. Of course, the feasibility of this solution depends on the execution time, table size etc. in your particular setup, and my suggestion would only make sense if it takes less than a minute or so instead of hours to generate the statistics.